# Openpyxl used to strip in for loop

Tags: for-loop

I am trying to do a simple cleaning in XLSX to remove leading blank spaces "$    xxxx" 
I was able to clean them in python, but not able to save them back in the excel file.

The info is in a table - the data I am cleaning is in column G (or 7) and I want to place the new data in column J (or 8)

```
import os
import openpyxl as xl


os.chdir(r'Documents\Py\Practice')
wb = xl.load_workbook('Unit.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active


for i in range (3, sheet.max_row+1):
    cell= sheet.cell(row=i, column=7)
    cell_strip = (cell.value.strip())
    cell_rev_value = sheet.cell(row=i, column=8)
    cell= cell_strip


wb.save('Unit_1.xlsx')
```